# Referenciação no padrão de projeto Flyweight

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, flyweight

Há uma coisa no Desing Pattern Flyweight que está me deixando realmente confuso.
Resumidamente, o padrão diz que para economizar memória numa situação em que se usa vários objetos parecidos, usa-se uma fábrica que devolve referências para um mesmo objeto num pool de flyweights ao invés de se instanciar milhares de objetos diferentes.

Eu também vi que para gerar independência de dados entre cada objeto, é necessário entender dois conceitos nesse padrão: Dado extrínseco e intrínseco, da qual eu também não entendi muito bem.

Se usando esse padrão eu estou usando referências a um mesmo objeto, não se terão problemas ao alterar o estado de apenas um objeto e acabar alterando o estado de todos? Por exemplo:  Eu desenvolvi um jogo em que, usando este padrão, eu possuo o objeto porta que é compartilhado entre todas as "portas" do jogo; o jogador controla um personagem que pode abrir ou fechar portas. Se todas as portas no jogo estão referenciando a um mesmo objeto, o jogo não terá o bug de quando o personagem abrir uma porta, inexplicavelmente todas as portas no mesmo cenário se abrem?

Eu vi que este problema poderia ser resolvido com o conceito de dado extrínseco e intrínseco, mas em todos os exemplos que eu li, eu não entendi como isso é implementado. Como, realmente é implementado um estado de independência de estado entre vários flyweights?

Answer (score 5):

Não sei se esses termos "intrínseco" e "extrínseco" tem uma conotação t
ecnica nesse contexto ou se eles fazem só parte da explicação do capítulo mas não tem nada de mágico. No final das contas, se você quiser usar a otimização descrita pelo padrão flyweight, os objetos compartilhados precisam ser imutáveis ou você vai encontrar esses problemas que você está imaginando. Se precisar ter alguma propriedade mutável que não é pra ser compartilhada ela precisa ser armazenada em um objeto separado do que a parte compartilhada.

Por exemplo, suponha que suas portas tenham duas propriedades: a imagem usada para representá-la e o estado de abertura (aberto/fechado). O estado vai ter que ser uma variável de instância armazenada separadamente por cada objeto porta mas as imagens são imutáveis e podem ser cacheadas e compartilhadas, como ocorre no padrão flyweight.

Comment: Eu adoro o exemplo que envolve texturas de objetos para explicar o *Fly Weight* :)

Answer (score 0):

Os dados intrínsecos são aqueles que fazem parte da essência de algo. O coração é algo intrínseco do ser humano.

Já os dados extrínsecos são aqueles que variam. O tom de pele é algo extrínseco do ser humano.

Normalmente se usa o *Flyweight* em coisas que não tem comportamento complexo porém acabam por consumir muita memória, como texturas.

Sim a mudança de "um objeto" causa efeitos colaterais em "outros". No seu exemplo uma opção seria fazer a `Porta` ser capaz de controlar o próprio comportamento dessa forma os "outros" objetos não serão afetados.

Você pode considerar o padrão de projeto *Caching* e *Object Pool* como alternativa ao *Flyweight* ou implementar no mesmo *Balking* ou *State*.